# How do rifled-bore shells remain pointing into the airflow?

Tags: projectile, aerodynamics

I can understand the logic behind spin-stabilizing bullets, which travel only a few hundred meters on fairly flat trajectories.

But I cannot understand the logic for artillery. Won't spinning shells remain the same orientation throughout the trajectory, causing them to belly flop on the target?

Comment: If they have an aerodynamic shape, the airflow will exert a torque on them. Won't that make them precess, like a gyroscope standing at an angle? Do shells spin? Some have fins.

Comment: Destin Sandlin did a few videos on stabilizing the Sidewinder missile. Not exactly what you asked, but interesting. Here is the first. [How the Warhead Works on the AIM-9 Sidewinder - Smarter Every Day 282](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8L83AHYum0)

Answer (score 2):

If  the shell keeps pointing in the same direction as the trajectory curves downward  from that direction, the air  will be hiting the shell from below. The effective total force acts a point called the *centre of pressure*, which (by the design of the shell)  is infront of the centre of mass. The air therefore exerts a torque on the  shell that tries to make it flip over on its back. However the shell is spinnning and so the torque instead makes it gyroscopically  precess so that turns sideways instead.  Indeed, after some oscillation just after it leaves the gun, friction will cause the shell to settle down with its nose pointing a little bit to the right (or left depending on the direction of spin) of the trajectory so that the precession causes  the nose to turn downwards at a rate that is  just  that required to keep pinting close to the direction of travel.

The slight sideways   yaw  causes a sideways force that makes the shell deviate a bit from the path expected from how the gun was aimed. This is called [drift](https://nigelef.tripod.com/fc_ballistics.htm), and has to be taken into acount when aiming the gun. (This drift has nothing to do with the coriolis force due to the earth's rotation). The drift is roughly proportional to the tangent of the angle of departure from the gun.

Comment: How does the shell precess at just the right rate?

Comment: A good question. I think that if not ,it starts "wobble" and this causes turbulence and friction that damps the wobble until the shell is back on path. If you stand right behind the gun you can  watch the projectiles go and see the initial wobble and its dying out. It must like the damping of nutation in a gyro with friction, but I have not tried modelling  it.